# Can use as.triangle function in R for data data with origin as dates?

Tags: r

I am trying to use function `as.triangle` from package `ChainLadder` in R but I have difficulties on how should this function should be used when my **origin** are not years but dates: 2019-09-30, 2019-08-31,...

My data looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: put your data directly in your question. You can use `dput`.